# python - fastest way to click mouse

Tags: python, click, mouse, pyautogui

I'm trying to make an auto click bot in python using pyautogui but this takes too much time (it runs in a loop, and xPos/yPos changes every time). What faster ways are there? Thanks for helping.

```
pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.001
pyautogui.click(xPos,yPos,button = 'left')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm testing three library: Pyautogui, Mouse and Pynput.
Links to libs:

- [Pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) last upd. OCT 2021
- [Mouse](https://github.com/boppreh/mouse) last upd. APR 2021
- [Pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) last upd. OCT 2021

Below code and result:

PYAUTOGUI version:

```
import pyautogui
def click_pyautogui(x, y, button):
    pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
    pyautogui.click(button=button)
```

MOUSE version:

```
import mouse
def click_mouse(x, y, button):
    mouse.move(x, y, absolute=True)
    mouse.click(button=button)
```

PYNPUT version:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
def click_pynput(x, y, button):
    mouse = Controller()
    mouse.position = (x, y)
    button = Button.left if button=='left' else Button.right
    mouse.click(Button.left)
```

wrapper:

```
def click(x, y, button):
    # pyautogui
    # click_pyautogui(x, y, button)

    # mouse
    # click_mouse(x, y, button)

    # pynput
    click_pynput(x, y, button)

import timeit
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(timeit.timeit("click(random.randrange(100), random.randrange(100), 'left')", number=100, globals=locals()))
```

**RESULTS** time for 100 cycles (average of 3, very small variations):

- Pyautogui: 22.07 sec
- Mouse    :  0.16 sec
- Pynput   :  0.20 sec

Mouse look as fastest library!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pynput`:

```
from pynput import mouse
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
import time

mouse = Controller()
one = time.time_ns()
for i in range(1000):
    mouse.click(Button.left)

two = time.time_ns()

print(two-one)
```

With this setup im able to execute 1000 clicks in .53 seconds.

Comment: thank you so much I increased(or decrease) the speed from 2 minutes to 10 seconds!

Comment: @ItayTsuk If my anwser helped, you can upvote/accept it by clicking the checkmark under the arrows.

Comment: it says that since I have less than 15 reputations I can't upvote, sorry

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment so I have to make a post, I just wanted to say that @swasher 's speed test is **incorrect**.

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
def click_pynput(x, y, button):
    mouse = Controller()
    mouse.position = (x, y)
    button = Button.left if button=='left' else Button.right
    mouse.click(Button.left)
```

This creates a new `Controller` object every time `click_pynput` is called, which is unnecessary and slow.

Creating the `Controller` object once before the function declaration is much better:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
_mouse = Controller()
def click_pynput(x, y, button):
    _mouse.position = (x, y)
    button = Button.left if button=='left' else Button.right
    _mouse.click(Button.left)
```

This in fact showed (on my pc) that pynput and mouse have the same speed.

Real **RESULTS** time for 100 cycles (average of 3, very small variations):

- Mouse : 0.1317509999498725 sec
- Pynput : 0.1323150999378413 sec

Also I tested just move speed and pyinput is slightly faster (1000000 iterations):

- Mouse : 24.206686099991202 sec
- Pynput : 20.718958700075746 sec